# How to test how many clicks my site can handle at once?

Tags: jquery, testing, webserver, load-testing, stress-testing

I tried many different stress test software such as loadimpact, webserver stress tool, but they don't literally click on my website.

I have a site that once the user clicks on it, it will send a post command using jquery and then that gets recorded.

I want a test to have 100 users literally click on my site at the same time to see if it will record all those clicks in my post command.

Is there any program out there that can literally generate 100 clicks on my site for a test ?

Comment: I have honestly never tested a site like that, there are many different things that come into play such as user PCs, internet speed, being on a shared server etc.

Comment: If you have written your code correctly then it shouldn't be an issue how many users click at the same time. The code should handle them all one by one and give back the responses

Comment: Maybe have a look at this, its not quite what you are looking for but will give you some indication as to what your site performance is http://www.webpagetest.org/

Comment: Hi Dave, yes that's true but if somehow 1 click gave an error from 100 clicks then I'm in big trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this, you could simply do :

```
$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
         $('#someElement').click();
    }
})
```

Save that in a page and open the page in 4 browser tabs etc.